# Deriving function for Information Content using continuity

Tags: analysis, information-theory

I'm trying to understand the derivation of Shannon's formula for entropy and information content. I follow the proof up to here:

For any $t,s \in (0,1]$
$$\frac{I(t)}{I(s)}=\frac{log(t)}{log(s)}=\frac{-Klog(t)}{-Klog(s)}$$ where K is an arbitrary positive constant

It is also given that I is a continuous function from (0,1] to $\mathbb{R}$

How can I show (I assume using some sort of continuity argument) that $I(x)=-Klog(x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: I'm using Shannon's "The Mathematical Theory of Communication", proof on Appendix 2 but it seems to skip the continuity argument needed to get from the fraction to the single function

Comment: You're already done - if for every $t,s$ $I(t)/I(s) = \log(t)/\log(s),$ then just picking any one particular value of $s$, say $1/2,$ yields that $I(t) = - \left(\frac{I(1/2)}{\log(2)}\right) \log(t).$ Here $I(1/2)/\log(2)$ is some constant.